# How Do I scroll to the #header DIV from an <a link at the bottom of the page and how to change animation speed - JQuery 1.8.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

How Do I scroll to the `#header` DIV from 
an `<a>` link at the bottom of the page and 
how to change animation speed - JQuery 1.8.3?

Using the best JavaScript code to!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by using offset to scroll to the desired element:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("header").offset().top
}, 500);
return false;
```

Where 500 is the speed in miliseconds. Be sure to include `return false;`.  This way you avoid the default browser action which will result in a slight flicker.

See http://jsfiddle.net/wf8dh/2/ for an example.

Answer (score 1):

scrolling animation should be done on html tag or body tag. But one thing to keep in mind.. try to store top offset value in a variable first as sometimes animation function may not able to process it immediately and it may append "undefined".
so use it like

```
           $("a").click(function(){
               var top = $("#header").offset().top;
               $("html, body").animate(function(){
                   scrollTop : top+"px"
               }, 2000);
          });
```

This is how scrolling animation works... :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [example](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/) I think you're looking for